# Check for undefined PHP method before calling?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

What can I use other than `if(!empty( $product->a_funky_function() ))` to check if the method is empty before calling it?

I've tried `method_exists()` and `function_exists()` and a whole plethora of conditions. I think the issue is that I need to have my `$product` variable there.

Please help.

Comment: @PatrickQ  I can see how that's confusing. Edited it now. I'm classing empty/value as it returning `null`, `0`, `0.0`, `false`, `array()` or some empty string

Comment: Okay, so how could you possibly expect to know what the result of a function is without actually calling that function?  I guess I'm still kind of confused about what you're really getting at here.  What is it that you don't like about `if(!empty( $product->a_funky_function() ))` ?

Comment: Psst: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Comment: I've figured it out. @PatrickQ, your comment helped me take a step back and actually think about it! thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fairly common pattern is to have two methods on your class, along the lines of `getField` and `hasField`. The former returns the value, and the latter returns true or false depending whether or not the value is set (where "set" can mean not null, or not empty, or whatever else you might want it to mean).

An example:

```
class Foo
{
    /** @var string */
    private $field;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getField()
    {
        return $this->field;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasField()
    {
        return $this->getField() !== null;
    }
}
```

This would then be used like:

```
if ($foo->hasField()) {
  $field = $foo->getField();
  ...
}
```

Often, like in this example, the `has...` method often just delegates to the `get...` method internally, to save duplicating the logic. If the getter contains particularly heavy processing (e.g. a database lookup or API call), you might want to factor in ways to avoid performing it twice, but that's a bit out of scope.

Comment: Thanks, this is basically what I'd started doing after reading some of the earlier replies but you're the first to say it so kudos to you!

Answer (score 1):

You need absolutely to call it so it can compute the value which it will return, so I think there is no other way to know if it will return something not empty without calling it...

Comment: Thanks, this wasn't quite the solution for me but I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call it.

```
$result = $product->getFunction();
if(!empty($result)) {
//your code here
}
```